# Change image source of span, once content area slide happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I currently have a problem. 
I built some kind of accordion on a website. Sliding works all fine, however, when I try to write a function to change the image src of the icon it does not work.

I have 3 span6, with the ID's swap1 to swap3. swap1 is visible at beginning, swap 2 and 3 are hidden.

This is my markup, here for swap1 only. swap2 and swap3 are built up the same:

```
<div id="swap1" class="span6">
     <h3>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet?
        <span class="expand"><img src="images/minus.png" /></span>
     </h3>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.....</p>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('logging');
    $('#swap2.span6 p').hide();
    $('#swap3.span6 p').hide();
    $(function() {
        $('#swap1 .expand').click( function() {
             $('#swap1.span6 p').slideToggle();
             $( "#swap1 .expand" ).attr('src', 'images/plus.png').load(function();
        });
        $('#swap2 .expand').click( function() {
             $('#swap2.span6 p').slideToggle();
             $( "#swap1 .expand" ).attr('src', 'images/minus.png').load(function();
        });
        $('#swap3 .expand').click( function() {
             $('#swap3.span6 p').slideToggle();
             $( "#swap1 .expand" ).attr('src', 'images/minus.png').load(function();
        });
     });
 });
```

First of all, the sliding works, the image src changing not at all. Second, I'm stuck with what happens after you slided. The image would stay at the changed state and would not change back regardless of the state (expanded/collapsed). I'm currently stuck, I tried to look it up how other accordions work, but nothing really helped.

http://jsfiddle.net/K2GpC/2/

Comment: $( "#swap1 .expand" ).attr('src', 'images/plus.png') shouldn't the selector be `#swap1 .expand img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) the I would suggest you change your jQuery to the following as it will allow for any number of divs rather than just the three you have:

```
$(function() {
    var divs = $('.span6'),
        content = divs.children('p');

    content.hide();
    content.eq(0).show();

    divs.click(function() {
        var thisContent = $(this).children('p');
        content.not(thisContent).slideUp(500, function() {
            $(this).parent().find('h3 .expand img').attr('src', 'images/plus.png');
        });
        thisContent.slideDown(500, function() {
            $(this).parent().find('h3 .expand img').attr('src', 'images/minus.png');
        });
    });
});
```

if you have other divs with the class of `span6` then you will need give your accordion divs another class name and then use that selector instead

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/K2GpC/3/)

Comment: Thank you. Both yours and Jagis answer were right, but I can only give one the green check :/ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`$( "#swap1 .expand" )` is a `<span>` They do not have `src` attributes.

Your selector should be :

`$( "#swap1 .expand img" ).attr('src', 'images/plus.png')`

Answer (score 1):

Check it out. It should be what you want.

```
$('#swap2.span6 p').hide();
$('#swap3.span6 p').hide();
$('.expand').click(function(){
    var expand = $(this);
    var p = expand.parent().next('p');
    var img = expand.find('img');
    p.slideToggle('normal', function() {
        if (p.is(':hidden')) {
            img.attr('src', 'images/plus.png');
        } else {
            img.attr('src', 'images/minus.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem :). We should exchange our knowledge :). What I would recommend you in adventure with jQuery is trying to minimize your code. As you can see in the code above, you can replace multiple click events with only one.

Comment: As a jQuery Greenhorn with nearly no knowledge in jQ/JS i'm happy when the code works :D First I need to know how to build a ship before I tune it and make it look pretty and sail fast.

Comment: another question, I want to have the h3 clickable, too. I changed the ('.expand') to ('.expand, h3'), didn't work out. h3 is not triggering the toggle slide.